# TYPO3 index_search no markup result in FLUID/ExtBase

Tags: typo3, fluid-layout, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

In default indexsearch extension i have highlighted keywords in search result, but when i use FLUID version it not work, I find that are different function it Controller, witch prepared description for default template and for FLUID.
typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Controller/SearchController.php

452 line --- prepared for FLUID

```
  $resultData['description'] = $this->makeDescription(
        $row,
        (bool)!($this->searchData['extResume'] && !$headerOnly),
        $this->settings['results.']['summaryCropAfter']
    );
```

`(bool)!($this->searchData['extResume'] && !$headerOnly)` shoud give '`false`' but didn't. I check ts `extResume = 1` and `headerOnly = false`. So it seems to be wrong construction?

When replace the `(bool)!($this->searchData['extResume'] && !$headerOnly)` to `false`. I get murkups but also i needed change output format in fluid template
from ---

```
    ...
    <f:if condition="{row.headerOnly} == 0">
        <p class="tx-indexedsearch-description">{row.description}</p> 
...
```

to -----

```
...
<f:if condition="{row.headerOnly} == 0">
    <p class="tx-indexedsearch-description"><f:format.html>{row.description}</f:format.html></p>
...
```

Now it work, but i still don't understand why it not work by default?

Comment: Thats fixed at least in 7.6 BUT it shows up the beginning of the page content - not the relevant part with the hits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative Method:

In the Searchform define a hidden Field: (Resource/Private/Partials/Form.html)

```
<f:form.hidden name="search[extResume]" value="1" />
```

In `Searchsresult.html` i would use format.raw instead of format.html.

```
<p class="tx-indexedsearch-description"><f:format.raw>{row.description}</f:format.raw>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its a bug - I already created a bugreport for this.

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77682

Maybe you can provide a patch and push it to the review-system - that would be very helpful!

Comment: its patched in the core now an on the review server:  https://review.typo3.org/#/c/49809/